# Using Selenium with Python, ElementClickInterceptedException: 'Other element would receive the click:', A way to extract this 'other element'.?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

When I try to click an element in a webpage, sometimes I run into the  **ElementClickInterceptedException** because if selenium executed the click, another element that is overlaying the element would receive the click and the console would print the error.

`ElementClickInterceptedException: Element <div class="potato"></div> is not clickable at point (324, 417). Other element would receive the click: <div class="carrot"></div>`

What I need is to extract the Other element, . (just an example, will change)

basically whatever element is blocking the click.

My current approach is to use a try-except to catch the exception message and use string methods to extract the text after 'click:'

```
except ElementClickInterceptedException as c_interrupt:
        other_element_raw= c_interrupt.msg
```

I'm looking for a built-in way or a much Efficient method.

Thanks in advance